# Insert self-referencing data into copy table

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have a self-referencing foreign-key constraint on my table. Because I'm transforming the schema, I'd like to copy the existing data into a new table with (more or less) the same structure:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  parent INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (parent) REFERENCES test(id)
);

CREATE TABLE copy(
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  parent INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (parent) REFERENCES copy(id) 
);
```

However, when [inserting the data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cfae4):

```
INSERT INTO copy(id, parent) SELECT id, parent FROM test;
```

MySQL gives me the common integrity error:

```
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row:
    a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`copy`, CONSTRAINT `copy_ibfk_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`parent`) REFERENCES `copy` (`id`))
```

It seems that MySQL checks the constraint after inserting each row instead of checking it after the whole insert. The exact same example [works fine in PostgreSQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/24638/1).

Is there any other way to insert this data or am I stuck with doing this in two steps like this?

```
INSERT INTO copy(id) SELECT id FROM test;
UPDATE copy
JOIN test ON test.id = copy.id
SET copy.parent = test.parent;
```

Comment: With MySQL you only have those two options: disabling the constraints (as shown by VMai) or do an insert/update in one transaction (as you do now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

before your INSERT and

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

after to disable the check of the foreign key constraint, so you don't have to worry about the order of the inserts:

See the documentation to [foreign_key_checks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks)

> foreign_key_checks
>
> If set to 1 (the default), foreign key constraints for InnoDB tables
>   are checked. If set to 0, such constraints are ignored. [...] Typically
>   you leave this setting enabled during normal operation, to enforce
>   referential integrity. Disabling foreign key checking can be useful
>   for reloading such tables in an order different from that required by
>   their parent/child relationships. See Section 14.6.6, “InnoDB and
>   FOREIGN KEY Constraints”. [...]
>
> **Note**
>
> Setting foreign_key_checks to 1 does not trigger a scan of the
>   existing table data. Therefore, rows added to the table while
>   foreign_key_checks = 0 will not be verified for consistency.

```
CREATE TABLE test(
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  parent INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (parent) REFERENCES test(id) 
);

CREATE TABLE copy(
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  parent INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (parent) REFERENCES copy(id) 
);

INSERT INTO test(id, parent) VALUES(1, null);
INSERT INTO test(id, parent) VALUES(2, 1);
INSERT INTO test(id, parent) VALUES(3, null);
INSERT INTO test(id, parent) VALUES(4, 2);
UPDATE test SET parent=3 WHERE id=1;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- Success with MySQL
INSERT INTO copy(id, parent) SELECT id, parent FROM test;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Your updated fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae623/1

Comment: Does MySQL has transactional support for the `SET` commands? (I assume no) In other words: what happens if the transaction fails before/during/after the insert? I'd rather not give up the constraint guarantee...

Comment: @r0estir0bbe  I don't see any problem for an one time job.